# Каким способом образовано слово ПОДКРАШЕННЫЙ?

Tags: словообразование, приставка, суффиксы

Каким способом образовано слово *подкрашенный*? У меня два варианта:

1) суффиксальным - к  слову *подкрасить* добавляем суффикс *-енн*;

2) приставочный - к слову *крашенный* добавляем приставку *-под*.

Comment: @telli, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Чем бы ни считали причастие, словообразование от этого не меняется.

Страдательные    причастия    настоящего      времени обычно образуются от основы глаголов настоящего времени I спряжения с помощью суффикса -ем- (-ом-) и II спряжения с помощью суффикса -им-.

**Страдательные    причастия**    прошедшего времени , как у нас ПОДКРАШЕННЫЙ, образуются от основы инфинитива (или основы глагола прошедшего времени) с помощью суффиксов  -нн-,-енн-, -т-.

Если в основу инфинитива входит суффикс -и.-, то при образовании причастия он опускается и используется суффикс причастия -енн-.

Разница будет, как этот суффикс назовут - словообразовательный или формообразующий. Но на экзамене такого вопроса нет.

Однозначно: подкрасить-подкраш**енн**ый - **суффиксальный**. Это во всех учебниках русского языка с 7 класса.

Comment: Людмила писала": "Чем бы ни считали причастие, словообразование от этого не меняется".

===

Только в первом случае процесс образования причастия называют СЛОВОобразованием, а в другом -- ФОРМОобразованием. Вот и вся разница!

Answer (score 1):

Слово ''подкрашенный'' образовано суффиксальным способом от глагола ''подкрасить'', который , в свою очередь, ''образовано приставочно суффиксальным способом от глагола ''красить''.

Answer (score 0):

> У меня два варианта...

Если причастие считать самостоятельной частью речи, то будет верен первый вариант: суффиксальный (**подкрас**ить -> подкраш-**енн**-ый).

Если же причастие считать глагольной формой, то нужно сначала найти начальную форму этого глагола, а затем определить, от какого слова этот глагол образовался.

У **подкрашенный** начальная форма (инфинитив) -- **подкрасить**. Образован этот глагол приставочным способом от **красить:**

*красить -> **под**-красить.*

См. http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#12_5 :

[image]

Comment: в ГИА причастие считают (вроде бы!) самостоятельной частью речи.

Тогда, telli, должен быть верен Ваш первый вариант: суффиксальный.

Comment: Слава, а чем же является ''и'' в этом глаголе? См.у Тихонова: **под/кра́с/и/ть**

Comment: А может быть так ,что слово образовано -- приставочно-суффиксальным способом?? К слову -- красить , добавляем приставку -под , и суффикс -енн??

Comment: Именно так, @telli, приставочно суффиксальным, если считать, что причастие - форма глагола. Но суффикс и. 
А если самостоятельная, то только - суффиксальным способом.

Comment: telli, ну почему же "подкрашенный" нужно образовывать от "красить", прибавляя к нему целых два аффикса? 

Ведь достаточно и одного -- при образовании "подкрашенный" от более близкого к нему по семантике, чем "красить", глагола "подкрасить".

Comment: 

Серж писал: "Слава, а чем же является ''и'' в этом глаголе? См.у Тихонова: под/кра́с/и/ть".

===

"И" в "подкрасить" -- суффикс. Но мы же ведём речь НЕ О МОРФЕМНОМ разборе, а о СЛОВООБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНОМ!

А ОБРАЗОВАНО "подкрасить" от "красить" -- с помощью приставки ПОД.

Comment: А-а, да, вы правы. Спутал.